# .Net Core reading SQL database return null values

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ado.net

First, have in mind that I am new to .net core. I am trying to read data from sql db, but for strings I am getting null values and for integers, I am getting 0 as a value.

Its interesting that I am getting the array list with 5 items (because of select top 5), and correct number of columns but like I said all values are either null or 0...

```
    public List<Student> Index()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        string connectionString = configuraton.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        string query = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tblStudents";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Student student = new Student();
                        students.Add(student);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return students;

    }
```

To be more clear, this is what I get for student when hitting break point

```
  id = 0
  contactPerson = null
  contactPhone = null
  createdDate = {01.01.0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

Comment: Your code creates a new empty student for every result row but doesn't use any of the row's values.

Comment: `string query = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tblStudents"` Where's your `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Panagiotis Kanavos comment: you create empty student. You need to map `reader` fields to your student object, eg.:

```cs
while (reader.Read())
{
    Student student = new Student();
    student.id = (int)reader["Id"];
    student.contactPerson = (string)reader["ContactPerson"];
    students.Add(student);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the all values in the reader but not saving valuesto the Student class, means you are adding empty classes into the `students` collection

```
 while (reader.Read())
  {
    Student student = new Student();
    students.Add(student);
  }
```

instead use something like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
      {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);
        student.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
        students.Add(student);
      }
```